# How to make input placeholder text not opaque when the text field background is opaque

Tags: html, css, input, colors, opacity

I have an input text field that is at { opacity: 0.2; } and has a background color of white (#ffffff) on top of a black and white image. The text field is at the correct opacity and looks great. But I want the placeholder text to be white and not effected by the opacity of the input field. I have tried looking up how to style placeholder text, but it still seems to be effected by the elements opacity. How do I go about doing this?

CSS for reference...

```
html, body {
padding:0;
margin: 0;
background-color:#222222;
}

.notifyEmail input[type="text"] {
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
background-color:#ffffff;
color: white;
padding-right:30px;
font-family:inherit;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:14px;
height:50px;
width:540px;
opacity:0.2;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your second class to this.   This specifies your background-color in rgba format and removes the opacity attribute:

```
.notifyEmail input[type="text"] {
      display:block;
      margin: 0 auto 10px 0;
      padding-right: 30px;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
      font-family:inherit;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      font-size: 14px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 540px;
}
```

Then add these classes:

```
.notifyEmail::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
      color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);  
}

.notifyEmail::-moz-placeholder
{
      color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);  
}

.notifyEmail:-ms-input-placeholder
{
      color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);  
}
```

Comment: The 'opacity' attribute applies to the element and all of it's children.  Whereas the alpha channel opacity (the 'a' of rgba) can be set on an individual element.